# remove all tags and create a new element that wrap inner html javascript

Tags: javascript, wrapper, replacewith

I'm completely new to javascript and I don't know which is the best way to solve a very simple problem.

I have to remove all `<p>` tags of an html page and put all the contents 
inside a unique `<p>` tag.

Which might be the cleanest solution to do that?

Text:

```html
<p> text1 </p>
<p> text2 </p>
....
<p> text n </p>
```

Expected result:

```html
<p>
text1,text2 ... text n
</p>
```

I started with this but I don't know how to go ahead:

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
                .getElementsByTagName('p'); //get all the p inside body 
var i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the `textContent` of all `p`s, remove all those existing `p`s from the document, then create a new `p` whose `textContent` is the others', joined by a separator if you want:

```js
const ps = [...document.querySelectorAll('p')];
const newText = ps
  .map(({ textContent }) => textContent)
  .join(',');
ps.forEach(p => p.remove());
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p')).textContent = newText;
```

```html
<p> text1 </p>
<p> text2 </p>
<p> text n </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following like code to fulfil your requirement.

```
org_html = document.getElementById("slidesContainer").innerHTML;
new_html = "<div id='slidesInner'>" + org_html + "</div>";
document.getElementById("slidesContainer").innerHTML = new_html;
```